Kano will not update/upgrade
I did see someone else getting the same 404 error when trying to update but no solution.
Is there a way to bypass raspbian stretch to further update? We have the kano build your own tablet. I have tried update and upgrade. I'm not the best at code but looking to see if anyone can guide me in the right direction.

I’m voting to close this question because it just does not make sense. You need to provide some background for your questions; start with an explanation of kano.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
